# Npm Start: getting error while starting starting server

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-start, expo

I'm trying to run npm server but i'm getting that error

```
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Danger World\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-02T10_54_16_635Z-debug.log
```

Anyone can please help me

Answer (score 0):

solution 1 ---

1. First add powershell to PATH as %SystemRoot%/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0.
2. open powershell as admin and write this command Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force.
3. last thing fire npm-windows-upgrade.

solution 2 ---

1. Add %SystemRoot%/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0 to your PATH Variable,
2. cmd+q and search env and hit enter
3. click environment variables in the advanced tab
4. find Path/PATH variable and click edit
5. Click new and paste %SystemRoot%/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
6. click ok and restart your terminal and try installing again